# Slice an image over two aribtray points

Tags: python, image, plot, 2d, slice

I am having trouble slicing an image using coordinates for a starting and stopping point. So far i have the following code

```
hdulist = fits.open(filename)
hdr= hdulist[0].header 

import numpy as np
import scipy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure, show
from astropy.io import fits
from scipy import interpolate

data=hdulist[0].data

#Make a line with "num" points
D, B = input('Enter the coordinates of the starting point:').split(',')
E, C = input("Enter the coordinates of the stopping point: ").split(',')
x0= float(D)
x1= float(E)
y0= float(B)
y1= float(C)

x = np.arange(data.shape[1])
y = np.arange(data.shape[0])
#length = int((np.hypot(x1-x0, y1-y0))) (can be used instead of num_points)
num_points = 1000
xvalues = np.linspace(x0, x1, num_points)
yvalues = np.linspace(y0, y1, num_points)
f = scipy.interpolate.interp2d(x, y, data) #default is linear


# Extract the values along the line
profile = f(xvalues, yvalues) #this gives me a 2D array, I think it needs to be 1D
#c = profile.flatten()
print(profile.shape)
```

The 'profile' is not linear but cubic. Is there a way for me to make the profile linear such that I can slice an image over the points between the starting and stopping point? All I want is to make 'profile' 1D instead of 2D.

I want to plot it like this:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import random
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure, show

vels = np.linspace(0, 530, len(profile))
fig = figure()
frame = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
frame.plot(vels, profile)
frame.set_ylabel('y-axis')
frame.set_xlabel('x-axis')
frame.grid(True)
show()
print(vels.shape)
print(profile.shape)
print(len(profile))
```

My code does not work because the plot that I get is not showing a slice of a line but a slice of a cube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of [interp2D](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp2d) it seems a grid is built from the interpolation. As so by intuition it seems to me you need the [diagonal](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diag.html) of that grid. Making a quick experiment with an adaptation of your code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure, show
from scipy import interpolate

X = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
Y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
R = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
data = np.sin(R)

x0 = 2
x1 = 23
y0 = 1
y1 = 36

rx0 = 4
rx1 = 2
ry0 = 7
ry1 = 32

x = np.arange(data.shape[1])
y = np.arange(data.shape[0])
num_points = 1000
xvalues = np.linspace(x0, x1, num_points)
yvalues = np.linspace(y0, y1, num_points)
f = scipy.interpolate.interp2d(x, y, data) #default is linear


# Extract the values along the line
profile = f(xvalues, yvalues)

xvalues2 = np.linspace(rx0, rx1, num_points)
yvalues2 = np.linspace(ry0, ry1, num_points)
profile2 = f(xvalues2, yvalues2)

plt.subplot(121)
plt.imshow(data.T, origin="lower", interpolation="nearest")
plt.scatter([x0, x1], [y0, y1])
plt.plot([x0, x1], [y0, y1])
plt.scatter([rx0, rx1], [ry0, ry1], c="r")
plt.plot([rx0, rx1], [ry0, ry1], c="r")
# plt.show()

diag = np.diag(profile)
diag2 = np.diag(profile2)
plt.subplot(122)
plt.plot(np.arange(diag.shape[0]), diag)
plt.plot(np.arange(diag2.shape[0]), diag2, c="r")
plt.show()
```

This returns the following:

[image: Slicing a 2D image]

NOTE: I did not took into account the coordinates into the 2D plot (that's why both lines look the same size).

Comment: Thank you very much, my code is now working the way i want it to!